# Nearest perimeter distance from centroid using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor, centroid

1. Main image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehqbs.png)
2. Have to separate the high intensity region (like this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLJC7.png)
3. Remove smaller pixel area region from image (like this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLCYD.png)
4. Now there are 4-5 objects in the image. Have to calculate the centroid of each objects and then generate a perimeter band (like this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lsCz.png)
5. Now calculate the distance (in pixels)  of nearest perimeter from each centroid and store those 4-5 distance values as final result.

How to do this? I have done step 1 to step 4, but could not find any solution for step 5. Can anybody help me out?

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I have done step 1 to step 4 and can not done step 5.

Comment: So what have you tried for step 5?

Comment: I could not find any solution. That's why I put this here for help

Comment: What do you mean by nearest perimeter. Can you just leave out the steps 1-4 and present an image for step 5 where you by hand insert what you mean? Just give an example. As it is, the question in unclear.

Comment: OK, just ignore first 4 steps. 
http://i.imgur.com/y6m3P4H.png
In this image there are 5 objects, and centroid of each objects are marked by blue point. I have to calculate the distance from centroid to nearest boundary. How can I do that?